# How to prevent favicon.icon leak both nginx and php version in Laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, favicon

I have already set up both Nginx and php.ini variables to off:

```
server_tokens off;
expose_php = Off
```

After restarting both Nginx and php-fpm services, I go ahead and open the browser's *Inspect Element* functionality and, as you know, you see several requests. I check everyone and I no longer see the "*Nginx version*" or "*powered by PHP 7.x*" information.

However, when I take a look at the "favicon.icon" request, both Nginx and PHP versions are shown!

What am I missing to fix it?

Comment: From what I can imagine, browser caches favicons for quick reloading.. You can see sometimes  the indication :`from memory cache` near the response status in browser. The response is coming from the memory cache of your device..

Comment: If you care about hiding software information completely (that is, remove the "nginx" Server header), you can do this easily with [ngx_security_headers](https://github.com/GetPageSpeed/ngx_security_headers) module.